# Regex for Multiple Key:Value Search Terms

Tags: c#, regex

I need a .NET (C#) regular expression for parsing a string of search terms. The terms are key:value pairs and are delimited by spaces. The thing that's throwing me for a loop is the fact that the key:value pairs may have spaces in the value.

Here's an example string:

```
f:john l:smith c:san francisco st:ca
```

I expect to get back the following terms:

```
  f:john
  l:smith
  c:san francisco
  st:ca
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: No, the key will never contain a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this one will work. It uses a lookahead to make sure that the last word doesn't have a `:` terminating it.

```
\b\w+:[\w\s]+\b(?!:)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try:

```
([\w]+)\:([\w\s]+)\s(?=([\w]+)\:)?
```

2 caveats:

- Each match will have three captures in it.  Ignore the last one.
- The input text *must* have a space at the end.